# Como convertir string en DateTime sin la hora

Tags: c#, visual-studio, datetime, parse.com

Tengo un string con el siguiente formato:

```
string hora = "04/12/2020";
```

Quiero convertir este string en `DateTime` pero sin incluir la hora.

He probado:

```
var dateTime = DateTime.ParseExact(hora, "MM/dd/yyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

y

```
DateTime enteredDate = DateTime.ParseExact(hora, "MM/dd/yyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

Pero me sigue dando la hora.

Como puedo hacerlo?

La idea que una vez que lo convierta solo con la fecha, le pueda quitar un dia con algo asi `enteredDate.AddDays(-1)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Los objetos DateTime siempre tienen una hora, por defecto a la medianoche. Puede acceder solo a la fecha usando DateTime.Date

```
enteredDate.Date
```

https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.datetime.date

Comment: Disculpas no hablo español